Spotify API get users saved albums 500 server error
I'm trying to use get users saved albums API call:
curl --location 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/albums' --header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_WITH_AUTH_SCOPE' 

response is:
{
    "error": {
        "status": 500,
        "message": "Server error."
    }
}

The bearer token has been negotiated as indicated in the documentation, incluting authorization scopes required for this call (user-library-read).

A server error is caused by Spotify, nothing you can do about that.

@0stone0 but this service is working when called via browser from their documentation
